# Redirect to another activity when link in webView is pressed

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

What I want to achieve: I have a webView in Activity A.I want to get the url and redirect to next Activity (Activity B) when link from webView in Activity A is pressed.Below is my code and shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not called when I press link in webView from Activity A.

```
    String url = "https://try.discourse.org/";
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("testUrl", url);
                startActivity(i);
                return true; 
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }


        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

        }

    });

 webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` has an overloaded version . override other version and then check .

Comment: what happens after you click the url, can you share the webView content..

Comment: @Alok content is loaded on the same webViews.It doesn't redirect to next activity

Comment: @ADM tried using this code. Didn't work
           
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    i.putExtra("test", request.getUrl().toString());
                }
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }

Comment: @topsecret can you confirm that page load is proper url load or something based on button action or async call. Also as per document post request will not be intercepted by this method.

Comment: @Alok WebView loads when app is first opened.No button action or async call.

Comment: i am saying there is chances that data is not even loading already exist in webview and just switched on that click event. something like single page Application.

Comment: @Alok shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not called when I set webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: That mean something wrong in that webpage, that is creating the situation in which callback is not called, what I suggest just try with simple page without any kind of script normal URL loading and let's see what happens..

Comment: @Alok works fine with simple page without any script..Why is method not being called when javaScript is enabled?

Comment: Now I am sure, certainly js is doing something wrong because of that Windows.location not getting changed..

Comment: @Alok any solutions for that problem?

Comment: You need to update your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` method